# How can I join two tables on like keys?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join two data sources that both key of off subnet starting IP. However the starting IPs in each are recoded differently. What syntax can i use to join the two tables based on the starting IP, sans the last character?

I need to build a result that has both description columns from each table.

Thank you!

```html
table 1:
"Starting IP" "Ending IP"  "Description_1" 
10.16.0.1     10.16.0.254  "REF#12345678"
10.16.1.1     10.16.1.254  "REF#987654321"
10.16.2.1     10.16.2.254  "REF#147258369"

table 2:
"Starting IP" "Ending IP"  "Description_2" 
10.16.0.0     10.16.0.255  "testing by Bill"
10.16.1.0     10.16.1.255  "production by Ann"
10.16.2.0     10.16.2.255  "VoIP by George"

desired query result:
"Starting IP" "Ending IP"  "Description_1" "Description_2"
10.16.0.0     10.16.0.255  "REF#12345678"  "testing by Bill"
10.16.1.0     10.16.1.255  "REF#987654321" "production by Ann"
10.16.2.0     10.16.2.255  "REF#147258369" "VoIP by George"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)` will return the string before `count` `delim` are encountered, and will probably serve you okay.

```
SELECT table2.*, table1.Description_2
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON 
   (substring_index(table2.`Starting IP`,'.',3)
   =substring_index(table1.`Starting IP`,'.',3))
```

however, this will not be very efficient. encoding it not as a string but actual bitstring will open up the possibility of using logical functions like bitwise AND and similar, which might be more efficient.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!